# $ \frac{2^{2n}}{2\sqrt{n}}<\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^{2} <\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$

Tags: inequality, induction

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $n>1$. Prove that:$ \frac{2^{2n}}{2\sqrt{n}}<\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^{2} <\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2=\binom{2n}{n}$.

We can prove the stronger than right inequality by induction.

We'll prove that
$$\binom{2n}{n}\leq\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{3n+1}}.$$
indeed, for $n=1$ we get an equality.

If $\binom{2n}{n}\leq\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$ then
$$\binom{2n+2}{n+1}=\binom{2n}{n}\cdot\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(n+1)(n+1)}\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{3n+1}}\cdot\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(n+1)(n+1)}\leq\frac{2^{2n+2}}{\sqrt{3n+4}},$$
where the last inequality it's just $5n\geq0$.

The left inequality it's induction again!